# How to create json schema object dynamically in typescript like this one?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I want to create one json schema object to use in json schema form. This object looks like this

```
 this.FormValueData = {

        'discountauthorizationelementsname': "userroleid,metalid,purityid,discountmodeid,categoryid,discounttypeid,discountvalue,creditpercent,creditvalue",
        'discountauthorizationelementstable': "discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization",
        'discountauthorizationelementscolmn':"userroleid,metalid,purityid,discountmodeid,categoryid,discounttypeid,discountvalue,creditpercent,creditvalue",
        'discountauthorizationelementspartabname': "discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization",
        'discountauthorizationviewfieldids':"110",
        'viewfieldids':"110",
        'moduleid':"110",
        'discauthpassword':"21212121212"

    };
```

Now I have written following lines

```
                let hidden_qp = {}

                let elementsname = this.lowermodname.concat("elementsname");
                let elementsnamevalue = "userroleid,metalid,purityid,discountmodeid,categoryid,discounttypeid,discountvalue,creditpercent,creditvalue";

                let elementstable = this.lowermodname.concat("elementstable");
                let elementstablevalue = "discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization";

                let elementscolmn = this.lowermodname.concat("elementscolmn");
                let elementscolmnvalue = "userroleid,metalid,purityid,discountmodeid,categoryid,discounttypeid,discountvalue,creditpercent,creditvalue";

                let elementspartabname = this.lowermodname.concat("elementspartabname");
                let elementspartabnamevalue = "discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization,discountauthorization";

                let viewfieldids = this.lowermodname.concat("viewfieldids");
                let viewfieldidsvalue = "110";

                let moduleid = "moduleid";
                let moduleidvalue = "110"

                let discauthpassword = "discauthpassword";
                let discauthpasswordvalue = "215521512521"

                hidden_qp[elementsname] = elementsnamevalue;
                hidden_qp[elementstable] = elementstablevalue;
                hidden_qp[elementscolmn] = elementscolmnvalue;
                hidden_qp[elementspartabname] = elementspartabnamevalue;
                hidden_qp[viewfieldids] = viewfieldidsvalue;
                hidden_qp['viewfieldids'] = viewfieldidsvalue;
                hidden_qp[moduleid] = moduleidvalue;
                hidden_qp[discauthpassword] = discauthpasswordvalue;
```

this given me same output but here key name are double quoted instead of single quotes like the first one and that is creating issues in my schema form builder. 
How to get the key values like 'discountauthorizationelementsname' instead of "discountauthorizationelementsname" . below is what I see in console for both the variables. 
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVDOT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come to know that I again need to do json.parse after doing json.stringify. 
so using this line

```
                  this.FormValueData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(hidden_qp));
```

has got me correct output.